# some confusions about ruby class inheritance

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

Consider the following code chunk.

```
 module Bosh::Director::Models  
      class CompiledPackage < Sequel::Model(Bosh::Director::Config.db)
      ...
      end
 end
```

I feel confused about `Sequel::Model(Bosh::Director::Config.db)`, what does the parenthesis mean? How class `CompiledPackage` inherit from `Sequel::Model(Bosh::Director::Config.db)`?

Comment: Not clear your question...

Comment: You need to get a better understanding of how Ruby works, and read the documentation for Sequel::Model; `Sequel::Model(Bosh::Director::Config.db)` [sets the dataset the model uses](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`Sequel::Model`corresponds to a table or a dataset in Ruby. `Bosh::Director::Config.db` may return a database type like mysql? So `Sequel::Model(Bosh::Director::Config.db)` is equal to `Sequel::Model(mysql)`, any class inherit from it behave like a mysql table or dataset. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

`Sequel::Model` is not a class - it is a method `Model` defined on module `Sequel` which creates a new anonymous class, does some fiddling with it depending on passed param and returns this class. It is defined like this (from github):

```
module Sequel
  ...
  def self.Model(source)
    if cache_anonymous_models && (klass = Sequel.synchronize{Model::ANONYMOUS_MODEL_CLASSES[source]})
      return klass
    end
    klass = if source.is_a?(Database)
      c = Class.new(Model)
      c.db = source
      c
    else
      Class.new(Model).set_dataset(source)
    end
    Sequel.synchronize{Model::ANONYMOUS_MODEL_CLASSES[source] = klass} if cache_anonymous_models
    klass
  end
  ...
end
```

When New class object is returned, inheritance is done as usual.

Comment: Huhh!! method named as a `constant`.. completely misleading... :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I agree it is, however they are pretty common, e.g. Array([1,2,3]) is a method defined in Kernel module (same as Float(), String() and few others)

Comment: Myself also agreed with you.. I don't know the significance of this *patterns*.

Comment: @BroiSatse, I can't understand your answer. I want to know what does the `()` of `Sequel::Model(Bosh::Director::Config.db)` mean?

Comment: @user2886717 - Since it is a method you just passing param to a method, same way as you would call `any_method(param)`.

Comment: Downvoter - can you give the reason for downvote, please?

Comment: @user2886717: That's the way arguments are passed to methods in Ruby (and pretty much every other mainstream programming language).